# how can i override my core CSS file class according to my custom _module.less?

Tags: magento2, css, less-css

This is my table in configuration and down there is core css class for that with name ".accordion .config .value" i want to change the width of that class from 44% to 100%.

[image]

I have my custom `_module.less` file  and in that i have but not working

```
@centerpadding: 21px 308px;

.accordion .config .value
{
  width: 100% ;
}
```

Comment: is that from a custom module?

Comment: sometimes it just ignores what you put in your custom theme unless you tag it !important;

Comment: yes this is a custom module

Comment: i am using !important  like `width: 44% !important` but it still picks `width: 44%`

Comment: there is no effect of using !important to the table size

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try adding your own css file in the system configuration page using the page layout?

create adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml file in your module and add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
      <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <head>
              <css src="Module_Vendor::css/config.css" order="100"/>
        </head>
      </page>
```

now create css file and add your css inside this file.